# Fast iteration over STL container in cython

Tags: python, c++, performance, stl, cython

I store some data in an `unordered_map` in cython and would also like to expose the data via the python `__iter__` interface. But iteration is significantly slower than the standard `dict` implementation in python. Can this be sped up?

The data structure looks something like this.

```
# distutils: language = c++

from cython.operator cimport dereference, preincrement
from libcpp.unordered_map cimport unordered_map
from libcpp.unordered_set cimport unordered_set

ctypedef unordered_map[int, unordered_set[int]] container_t


cdef class Base:
    """
    Base class holding the data.
    """
    cdef container_t container

    def __init__(self, int n):
        # Populate the container ([] creates an entry).
        for i in range(n):
            self.container[i]

    def iterate(self):
        """
        Iterate in C++ without python interaction as a baseline.
        """
        it = self.container.begin()
        while it != self.container.end():
            preincrement(it)
```

I've tried two different implementations of `__iter__` to support python iteration: one with `yield` and the other using a dedicated iterator (see below).

```
cdef class A(Base):
    """
    Simple implementation using `yield`.
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        it = self.container.begin()
        while it != self.container.end():
            yield dereference(it).first
            preincrement(it)
    
    
cdef class Iterator:
    """
    Dedicated iterator.
    """
    cdef Base container
    # Using container_t.iterator doesn't seem to work.
    cdef unordered_map[int, unordered_set[int]].iterator it
    
    def __init__(self, Base container):
        self.container = container
        self.it = container.container.begin()
    
    def __next__(self):
        if self.it == self.container.container.end():
            raise StopIteration
        value = dereference(self.it).first
        preincrement(self.it)
        return value
    
    
cdef class B(Base):
    """
    Implementation using a dedicated iterator.
    """
    def __iter__(self):
        # Updated interface following @DavidW's comment.
        return Iterator(self)
```

So let's compare the runtimes.

```
# Number of elements in the container.
n = 1_000_000

%%timeit x = {i: set() for i in range(n)}
# Baseline python implementation.
list(x)
# 5.64 ms ± 14 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit x = A(n)
list(x)
# 19.2 ms ± 141 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit x = B(n)
list(x)
14.6 ms ± 61.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Using a dedicated iterator is faster than using `yield` but still about 3x slower than the standard `dict` implementation. Iteration over the STL container is faster, however.

```
%%timeit x = Base(n)
x.iterate()
# 1.75 ms ± 34 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Is there a way to get comparable performance with `dict` (or better)? Or is this just a fundamental limitation due to hopping back and forth between python ints and C++ ints? For reference, the full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/tillahoffmann/af4af7186d2522ebe9820a9be39bcda6).

Comment: My first assumption would be, that quite some time is used to create python-objects (ints) from  c-int: this is something that the pure python version doesn’t have to do. The situation is similar to numpy arrays: if you use iteration it is slower than python-lists, the trick is to use c-functionality which would not convert c-values to python objects.

Comment: `cdef container_t* ptr` would probably be better off as `cdef Base base` - that would make sure that you keep `base` alive while its iterators are alive, and probably let you write a more useful constructor.

Comment: Good point, @DavidW. Integrated your suggestion above. Timings remain pretty much the same.